# Awk colors don't show up in Xterm

Tags: bash, awk, xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole

I am writing a user command as an alias that use awk printing output in different colors.

The little snippet I came up with works fine in KDE Konsole but not in xterm or gnome-terminal.

My shell is a BASH on SLES11 and the terminal is set to XTERM

```
myuser@myhost:~> env |grep -i term
TERM=xterm
COLORTERM=1
```

The alias is defined as follows:

```
alias myCustomPS="\
   awk '{ \
      gsub(/\.CONTEXT/,\"\", \$11);  \
      split(\$11,v,\"_D\");  \
      split(\$13,h,\".\"); \
      if (\$1==\"usr1\") 
         printf \"pid [\033[1;37;48;2;0;0;128m %5s \033[0m] [\033[1;37;48;2;0;0;128m %.8s \033[0m] \033[1;37;48;2;0;0;128m %-8.10s \033[0m D%-8s\n\", \$2, \$1, h[1], v[2]; \
      else if (\$1==\"usr2\") \
         printf \"pid [\033[1;37;48;2;0;170;170m %5s \033[0m] [\033[1;37;48;2;0;170;170m %.8s \033[0m] \033[1;37;48;2;0;170;170m %-8.10s \033[0m D%-8s\n\", \$2, \$1, h[1], v[2]; }'"
```

the output I get is displaying correctly ONLY in Konsole.

Both xterm and gnome-terminal instead don't show it correctly.
In Xterm no color at all is shown, in gnome-terminal only the font color is shown, no background.

any idea, or alternative ways to universally colorize the awk output?
Thanks, 
Roberto

Comment: This is really hard to test without representative sample input.  Could you provide some, or perhaps pare down the script to a bare minimum which attempts to colorize any random piece of text?

Comment: Don't hard-code escape sequences. Use `tput` or similar to query the terminal for the sequence to use for the current terminal type. I'm going to assume that those sequences just aren't correct for xterm or gnome-terminal. I know that at least in supported colors `Konsole` supposedly has much broader support for what colors are available (any arbitrary color actually I believe).

Comment: If i remember correct you need to set TERM to xterm-color or something similar to get colors in xterm, try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003136/what-is-the-difference-between-xterm-color-xterm-256color

Comment: You can't feel good about all that escaping - put this in a function or a shell script, not an alias.

Comment: Well the alias is indeed defined into a shell script and used in the definition of a function in that same shell script. I'll try to make it much simpler and provide a usable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet uses the RGB flavor "2" in the escape sequence, which should work with xterm after [patch #282](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282) (which seems a little old, but SLSE 11 is a few months older than that).

If you must hardcode things, the RGB flavor "5" is more portable.  But portable applications use something like [tput](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) rather than relying on constants.

The "2" referred to is in this string (repeated several times):

```
\033[1;37;48;2;0;0;128m
             ^
```

and is mentioned in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) in the paragraph discussing ISO-8613-6.